# How to measure trailing spaces using SkiaSharp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skia, skiasharp

SkiaSharp doesn't consider the white spaces, when a text contains white spaces in prefix or suffix. It returns the text width only and ignore the white spaces. I am using the following code snippet to measure a string.

```
        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
        paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Calibri");
        paint.TextSize = 15;

        SKRect rect = new SKRect();
        paint.MeasureText(" Test ", ref rect);
```

Is there any option to measure a text with trailing spaces using SkiaSharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the return value of `MeasureText`:

```
float width = paint.MeasureText(" Test ", ref rect);
float whiteSpaceWidth = width - rect.Width;
```

And if you want to adjust `rect` to include the whitespace also:

```
rect.Left -= whiteSpaceWidth / 2;
rect.Right += whiteSpaceWidth / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a "left-to-right" country.

`rect.Left` is the width of the leading whitespace, while `rect.Width` is the width of the text without leading & trailing whitespace.

`rect.Right` should be the width of the text with leading whitespace, while the return value of `MeasureText` is the total width including leading & trailing whitespace.

Even the [original skia api reference](https://api.skia.org/classSkFont.html#ab50421ba467b68bebac4282f6057cfc5) is not very helpful.